# Changing to ancestor directory without typing all the dots and slashes

Tags: command-line, zsh, directory, line-editor

In zsh, how do I refer to the grandparent directory with `...` rather than
`../..`, and so forth?  I used to have this in oh-my-zsh and prezto.

PS.  Ideally, `M-3 .` should yield `../../..`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code does the trick:

```
rationalise-dot() {
  if [[ $LBUFFER = *.. ]]; then
    LBUFFER+=/..
  else
     LBUFFER+=.
  fi
}
zle -N rationalise-dot
bindkey . rationalise-dot
bindkey -M isearch . self-insert
```

Comment: (from https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.unix.shell/I_GsEZNaXpU/Ie_cfiIc3SkJ). Googling `rationalise-dot` will show various improvements that people have added to that.